# Validation of Devexpress TokenBox from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I am using DevExpress TokenBox. It shows error text when i write wrong expression, but I also need to validate it from JavaScript. When I click a button there should be alert "Text is correct" or "Text is wrong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this: [ASPxTokenBox Client side Validation](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T389912/aspxtokenbox-client-side-validation)

> Add Client side event and there you can get that it is valid or not..
>   If you want to check it another control event then please use
>   [GetIsValid](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientTokenBox.members) method.

Go through [ASPxTokenBox client side members documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientTokenBox.members) and you can easily implement your functionality as you want. Remember to set the control's **ClientInstanceName** property.
e.g.

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Width="170px" ClientInstanceName="tbAge">
     <ValidationSettings ValidateOnLeave="False" EnableCustomValidation="True">
     </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

//js

```
if (tbAge.GetIsValid()
```

References:
[How to assign/retrieve ASPxTokenBox token value (different from display text) on the client and server side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T459083/how-to-assign-retrieve-aspxtokenbox-token-value-different-from-display-text-on-the)